# Urllib2 Not installed?

Tags: python, api, urllib2

I coded this:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

import json
import time
import urllib2

...

req=urllib2.Request(api_url,binary_data,header)

f=urllib2.urlopen(req)
```

My python version is the 3.6.5 so i´m supposed to have the urllib2 installed already but every time i get this error:

```
import urllib2 
ModuleNotFoundError: no module named 'URLLIB2'
```

I changed the name to urllib3 as it appears in my anaconda folder but it  crashes anyway....
what do i do?

Comment: Don't manually type error messages here. Copy-paste them as it is.

Answer (score 2):

Urllib2 is meant for Python 2, it is no longer used in Python 3.  The standard module is now called `urllib` (you can find the documentation for it here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.html).

Try this instead:

```
import urllib.request
req=urllib.request.Request(api_url,binary_data,header)
f=urllib.request.urlopen(req)
```

`urllib.request.Request()`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.Request
`urllib.request.urlopen()`:https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlopen

---

Comment: If i change it to urllib it works but it crashes again in 
        req=urllib.Request(api_url,binary_data,header)
        f=urllib.url(req)
as it says: Module 'urllib' has no attribute 'Request'

Comment: @XabierMikel  Yes that is because the coding has changed since Python2, I will type up the working equivalent.

Comment: @XabierMikel  Basically whatever code you are using, is meant for the wrong version.  Try the above.

Comment: thank you buddy, it wont crash now.
Anyway something messed with the index because now the error is
TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation..
 i will try to move some tabs and stuff and see what happens

Comment: Somewhere there are too few/many spaces, or you have forgotten to indent it in an appropriate place

Comment: i fixed the index issue somehow. But now we are back to the
AttributeError: module 'urllib' has no attribute 'request'

Comment: Have you used `import urllib.request` and not `import urllib`? @XabierMikel

Comment: Nope, i didnt.
with urllib.request it runs, but crashes anyway. I got this:

  File "C:\Users\Xabier\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py", line 526, in open
    response = self._open(req, data) 
  File "C:\Users\Xabier\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\http\client.py", line 1026, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "C:\Users\Xabier\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\socket.py", line 710, in create_connection
    sock.settimeout(timeout)
TypeError: an integer is required (got type dict)

Comment: Right, that has been caused by whatever you passed to the `Request()` object.  I can't help with that unless you provide some runnable example I can run for myself.